# Remove index.php from URL Apache 2.4

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04

I have been trying to remove index.php from my application since a day. I have tried everything but am not able to remove it. The problem is - I am not allowed to have `.htaccess` file in the project directory and the config in .htaccess file which works on my local dev machine does not work there.

The config I have on my local machine is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Rules to serve URLs which point to files directly
    # ----------
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I am aware that I cannot use RewriteBase directive inside the host configuration file (/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf/000-default.conf). However disabling that doesn't work either.

Why is this problem so difficult? There are a lot more complicated redirections that are working perfectly, but there seems to be no definite solution to removal of index.php from the URL!

EDIT: It is installed on a Ubuntu 14.04 machine.

Comment: I hope you were able to get your issue resolved.  If my answer was helpful to you, I'd appreciate if you could mark it as accepted so I can get credit for it.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you must avoid using .htaccess, another directive you could try if you're having trouble with mod_rewrite is to use the ErrorDocument directive such as the following:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

If you go that route, you may need to tweak the application code slightly - like at the top of the index.php file, you might need to set $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] to $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].  Compare the $_SERVER contents between dev and production to get a better idea if that doesn't do it.

If you can edit the conf file as you noted, and if it's not a policy / security issue to use .htaccess, you could always enable .htaccess for the site by using the AllowOverride directive in the conf file.